# React Jest es6 (rest spread operator) babel configuration not working

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I am try create app with `react-tool-box`. Also I try use `Jest` for testing,

but get this test fails. It look like es6 configuration problem for `Jest`.

● Test suite failed to run

```
/home/user/project/react-tool-box/react-toolbox-example/src/frontend/components/PurpleAppBar.js: Unexpected token (5:34)
    3 | import theme from './PurpleAppBar.css';
    4 | 
  > 5 | const PurpleAppBar = ({ children, ...other }) => (
      |                                   ^
    6 |   <AppBar {...other} theme={theme}>
    7 |     Hello developer!
    8 |     {children}
```

my `jest.config.js`:

```
{
"moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "jsx"
],
"scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
"moduleNameMapper": {
    "App": "<rootDir>/src/frontend/components/App.js"
}
```

}

my `.bablerc`:

```
 {
  "presets": [
     "react",
     "es2015"
  ]
}
```

and `package.json` scripts:

```
...    
"scripts": {
        "start": "node_modules/.bin/cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --colors --config webpack.config.js",
        "build": "node_modules/.bin/cross-env NODE_ENV=production UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=100 webpack --config webpack.config.js",
        "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
        "test": "jest --config jest.config.js"
      },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found answer [here](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/170).

add "stage-3" to .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-3", "react"]
}
```